# history.pushState breaking on browser back button

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history, pushstate

I'm working on a single page application where each section is loaded via ajax. The homepage is its own page, then you click 'About' and it takes you to the single page app. I've gotten the url to change on each section and the back and forward buttons on the browser to work with this snippet:

```
$('.down-button').on('click', function() {
        var stateObj = { principles: "about-principles" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-principles");
        $('#principles-wrap').scrollintoview({ duration: 1000 });
    });
```

However, when you click all the way back to the homepage, the homepage does not refresh, you remain on the 'About' page. Or, if you click on a link back to the homepage, you get a 404 error.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Here is the rest of the code:

```
function button_scroll () {
// Call scrollIntoView js file into this 
$.getScript("/js/jquery.scrollintoview.min.js", function() {
    $('.down-button').on('click', function() {
        var stateObj = { principles: "about-principles" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-principles");
        $('#principles-wrap').scrollintoview({ duration: 1000 });
    });
    $('.up-button-principles').on('click', function() {
        var stateObj = { mission: "about-mission" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-mission");
        $('#mission-wrap').scrollintoview({ duration: 1000 });
    });
    $('.down-button-principles').on('click', function() {
        var stateObj = { snapshot: "about-snapshot" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-snapshot");
        $('#snapshot-wrap').scrollintoview({ duration: 1000 });
    });
    $('.up-button-snapshot').on('click', function() {
        var stateObj = { principles: "about-principles" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-principles");
        $('#principles-wrap').scrollintoview({ duration: 1000 });
    });
    $('.down-button-snapshot').on('click', function() {
        var stateObj = { people: "about-people" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-people");
        $('#people-wrap').scrollintoview({ duration: 1000 });
    });
    $('.up-button-people').on('click', function() {
        var stateObj = { snapshot: "about-snapshot" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-snapshot");
        $('#snapshot-wrap').scrollintoview({ duration: 1000 });
    });

});
```

}

```
//Dropdown
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    resize_mission();
    resize_principles();
    resize_snapshot();
    resize_people();
    button_scroll();
});
var dropDown = $('.dropdown');
$('h3.about').on('click', function() {
    dropDown.slideDown('fast', function() {
        var url = 'about2.php'
        var stateObj = { mission: "about-mission" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, null, "about-mission");
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            resize_mission();
            resize_principles();
            resize_snapshot();
            resize_people();
            button_scroll();
        });
    });
});
```

});

This is all I'm doing. No plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Are you stopping the default action of the click event to homepage on the about page? As in are you using `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` on a link click on your about page? Also are you stopping the default behaviour on the hashchange event? We might need to see some more code around your implementation of history. Are you using any plugins for history?

Comment: I added the rest of my code. And no, I'm not doing a preventDefault() or using a plugin. You can see the page here: http://teneo.telegraphbranding.com/

Comment: You might want to take a look at Ben Alman's JQuery BBQ plugin (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). Its really easy to use and works cross browser (as well as with older browsers which your current code wont). I use it all the time on my projects (as do a lot of JQuery developers) and it makes life a lot easier :). I will however take another look at your updated code as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: How would I implement the BBQ plugin on my site? I'm a bit confused by the documentation. Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It takes some fiddling to get to understand how to do it initially :). Ben also has an even simpler plugin (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) if you don't need all the extra functionality that BBQ offers. Otherwise take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin as a lot of history plugins are mentioned. Perhaps you can find one there thats easier to understand and more suitable for what you need in your situation.